# Mongoose .insertMany only saving object id and and version

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, bulkinsert

while using mongoose insertMany to populate a collection I noticed it's only saving the **object id** and **version** for each data in the array as such

[image: Mongo]

but my model and data are structured as shown in code below

```
//SCHEMA MODEL
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const staffSchema = new Schema({
    Phone: { String },
    Timestamp: { String },
    Fullname: { String },
});

module.exports = { staffConvert: model("staff", staffSchema) };
```

though my actual data is coming from converting excel to json but this a sample of the data

```
 //SAMPLE DATA ARRAY 
    const data = [
                    {
                        Phone: "92893249",
                        Timestamp: "8/24/2020 10:08:25",
                        Fullname: "Musa Yahaya",
                    },
                    {
                        Phone: "92893249",
                        Timestamp: "8/24/2020 10:08:25",
                        Fullname: "Musa Yahaya",
                    },
                ];



                try {
                    if (data.length === 0) return console.log("No data to upload");
                    await staffConvert
                        .insertMany(data)
                        .then((docs) => {
                            console.log(
                                "success_msg",
                                "Staffs record uploaded successfully" + " " + docs
                            );
                            // req.flash("success_msg", "Staffs record uploaded successfully");
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(
                                "Staffs record uploaded failed" + " " + error.message
                            );
                        });
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("Staffs record uploaded failed" + " " + error.message);
                    // req.flash(
                    //  "error_msg",
                    //  "Staffs record uploaded failed" + " " + error.message
                    // );
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make change to your model. You're defining your attribute as object type. If you want to define it like that, you have to explicitly tell mongo that it's string type not object.

```
const staffSchema = new Schema({
Phone: String,
Timestamp: { type: String },
```

});

This should solve your issue

Comment: can't believe i missed that, thanks @r_dmr